# How to build GnuPG (gpg) from source; symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: gpgrt_set_confdir, version GPG_ERROR_1.0

Tags: software-installation, compiling, gnupg

My Resources:

1. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/175/114401
2. Source code: https://gnupg.org/download/index.html

My current version of `gpg` is:

```bash
$ gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.19
libgcrypt 1.8.5
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: /home/gabriel/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

I'd like to build and install 2.3.7. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04. The only way I can see to do that is from source.

I tried building and installing gpg from source on Ubuntu 20.04, like this (I obtained all download links [here](https://gnupg.org/download/index.html)):

```bash
# verify version before the update
gpg --version

# 1. Build & install dependencies (needed libraries)

wget https://gnupg.org/ftp/gcrypt/libgpg-error/libgpg-error-1.45.tar.bz2
wget https://gnupg.org/ftp/gcrypt/libgcrypt/libgcrypt-1.10.1.tar.bz2
wget https://gnupg.org/ftp/gcrypt/libksba/libksba-1.6.0.tar.bz2
wget https://gnupg.org/ftp/gcrypt/libassuan/libassuan-2.5.5.tar.bz2
wget https://gnupg.org/ftp/gcrypt/ntbtls/ntbtls-0.3.1.tar.bz2
wget https://gnupg.org/ftp/gcrypt/npth/npth-1.6.tar.bz2
wget https://gnupg.org/ftp/gcrypt/pinentry/pinentry-1.2.0.tar.bz2

tar jxvf libgpg-error-*.bz2
tar jxvf libgcrypt-*.bz2
tar jxvf libksba-*.bz2
tar jxvf libassuan-*.bz2
tar jxvf ntbtls-*.bz2
tar jxvf npth-*.bz2
tar jxvf pinentry-*.bz2

cd libgpg-error-!(*.bz2)
time (./configure && make && sudo make install) && cd ..

cd libgcrypt-!(*.bz2)
time (./configure && make && sudo make install) && cd ..

cd libksba-!(*.bz2)
time (./configure && make && sudo make install) && cd ..

cd libassuan-!(*.bz2)
time (./configure && make && sudo make install) && cd ..

cd ntbtls-!(*.bz2)
time (./configure && make && sudo make install) && cd ..

cd npth-!(*.bz2)
time (./configure && make && sudo make install) && cd ..

cd pinentry-!(*.bz2)
time (./configure && make && sudo make install) && cd ..

# 2. Build & install gpg

wget https://gnupg.org/ftp/gcrypt/gnupg/gnupg-2.3.7.tar.bz2
tar jxvf gnupg-*.bz2
cd gnupg-!(*.bz2)
time (./configure && make && sudo make install) && cd ..

# verify the version after the update
gpg --version
```

I don't see any errors when scanning the output (although it's a lot to look at), and the `&&` symbols should stop if there were errors, rather than cd'ing back up with `cd ..` after building and installing.

However, `gpg --version` still shows `2.2.19`, not `2.3.7`. Why?

Manually trying to run it fails with this error too:

```bash
$ gnupg-2.3.7/bin/gpg --version
gnupg-2.3.7/bin/gpg: symbol lookup error: gnupg-2.3.7/bin/gpg: undefined symbol: gpgrt_set_confdir, version GPG_ERROR_1.0
```

Why? Running it directly like that should work.

---

Update: here are a few references and resources I found which may help me as I continue trying to solve this problem myself:

1. [Google search for "gpg build from scratch"](https://www.google.com/search?q=gpg+build+from+scratch&oq=gpg+build+from+scratch&aqs=chrome..69i57.5818j0j9&client=ms-android-google&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)

   1. https://njh.eu/gpg - looks very promising! I need to try this.

Comment: Note: if anyone knows how I can download the 2.3.7 binary, or use `apt` to install it instead, on Ubuntu 20.04, I'd like to know that too, since building from source code is always a pain.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and gave up building from source, just installed [Kleopatra](https://www.openpgp.org/software/kleopatra/) and that updated GnuPG

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kleopatra
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. The versions that you download from https://gnupg.org/ftp/gcrypt install to /usr/local/... while your original versions sit into /usr/... . It creates possible mismatch of headers/libraries.  I had to remove all libraries to be relaced and gpg package first and build after that.
2. You need to build in the following order

- npth
- libgpg-error
- libgcrypt, libksba, libassuan
  (ntbtls, pinentry are optional)